# using ng-style to convert new height for div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am going to try to set a new height on a div, using `ng-style`. 
I am trying to calculate the new height for this div with the factor of the width. That looks like this:

```
var a = bigImage.style.width/topImage.style.width;
var heigthNewImage = bigImage.style.height/a;
```

The only problem is that it gives me `NaN`.
So how do I have to get the values of the width and height in the right ways of the div elements? So that it gives me the right values back to set height of another div element.

```js
var bigImage = document.getElementById('bigImage').style;
var topImage = document.getElementById('topImage').style;
var a = bigImage.width/topImage.width;
var heigthNewImage = bigImage.height/a;
vm.convertheight = {
  height: heigthNewImage
};
```

```css
body{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

/*.small-image{

position:sticky; top:0; left:0;
}*/

#bigImage{
 width:3000px;
 height: 2000px;
 
}
#topImage{
 position:sticky;
  top:0;
  left:0;
 height:250px;
 width:300px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: url('../img/scale.jpg');
 background-size: 400px 250px;
}

.movingBox{
 /*height:50px;*/
 width:300px;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="topImage" ng-mousedown="vm.mouseDown()">
  <div class="movingBox"  ng-mousemove="vm.mouseMove()" ng-mouseup="vm.mouseUp()" ng-style="{ 'height' : vm.convertheight + 'px' }"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <img id="bigImage" src="assets/img/scale.jpg" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = bigImage.style.width/topImage.style.width;
```

you're getting NAN most likely because you're doing the calculation before the dom is actually rendered resulting in a 0/0.

Assuming those elements do exist in your dom , if you wrap your code inside a $timeout, the code will be executed after the rendering has completed

```
$timeout(function(){
  $scope.height= bigImage.style.width/topImage.style.width;
})
```